# GORM: saving a manyTomany relationship

Tags: grails, grails-orm

just trying to persist a relationship between GORM entities, and an overflow error appends on mapping during save.

1) I create a manyTomany relationship between User and DataStore:

```
User entity: 
...
static belongsTo = DataStore
    static hasMany = [groups: Groups,dataStore:DataStore]

    Profile profile
    Contacts contact
    DataStore dataStore
...

DataStore entity:
...
static belongsTo = [service:Service]
    static hasMany = [users:User]

    Service service
    List<User>   users
...
```

2) Calling the service from a controller to save datas:

```
 UserRole.create user, roleCustomer, true
        UserRole.create user, roleAdmin, true
        dataStoreService.createDS('ds',profile.service,user)
```

3) Service logic:

```
 @Transactional
    def createDS(ds,service,user) {
        def key = service.domainkey
        if (user && key) {
            DataStore ds = new DataStore(ds:ds)
            ds.validate() ? ds.save(flus:true) : ds.errors.allErrors.println()
            ds.addToUsers(user).save(flush:true)
            service.addToDataStore(ds).save(flush:true)
            user.setDataStore(ds)
...}
```

4) The weird error i need to solve:

Stacktrace follows:
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.exceptions.ControllerExecutionException: Executing action [sendOrder] of controller [$$.StoreController]  caused exception: Runtime error executing action
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:195)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
    at net.bull.javamelody.JspWrapper.invoke(JspWrapper.java:149)
    at net.bull.javamelody.JdbcWrapper$DelegatingInvocationHandler.invoke(JdbcWrapper.java:259)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:202)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.exceptions.ControllerExecutionException: Runtime error executing action
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.apache.commons.validator.EmailValidator.stripComments(EmailValidator.java:246)
    at org.apache.commons.validator.EmailValidator.isValid(EmailValidator.java:95)

Any help please?

Comment: Are you sure that problem in service? Provide a controller code.

Comment: controller code added: calling service logic here to create the DS ans user accordingly.

Comment: Are you performing any custom validation in the domain `DataStore`?

Comment: what is ds.save(flus:true)? flus?

Comment: @ dmahapatro: No custom validation in DS class, only a before validate converter to uppercase.                                          @ Mr. Cat: it's a (flush:true), sorry for the typo.

Comment: After a cleanup of the model (service was  containing a useless manytomany reslationship to DS), i have the following error focused on email validator (contraint to validate the user mail as unique), it seems that it causes the trouble here... How to keep this contraint ?

Comment: Thanks for letting us know the problem, was not sure whether my answer was completely wrong. Try to play around with the constraint and see your expectations in terms of requirements and behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just redone my model following hibernate doc:

```
class User implements Serializable {

    static hasMany = [dataStores:DataStore,contacts:Contacts,groups: Groups]

    Profile profile
    Contacts contacts
    List<DataStore> dataStores
```

with contraint: `dataStores nullable:true`

And DS entity:

```
class DataStore implements Serializable{

    static hasMany = [users:User,contacts:Contacts]
    static belongsTo = [service:Service]

    Service service
    User users
```

removes definetely the several overflows and keeps the model reliable.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT

After looking again at the stack trace the problem has nothing to do with Melody (maybe? maybe not?) but let us know what was wrong).

Check the email reference of the User (Not sure in which sub-domain class it is located, maybe contact class? print it or use a debugger to inspect the domain values and then double-check your constraints) .  If the email issue is not related to your domain classes, then double-check again melody...

org.apache.commons.validator.EmailValidator.isValid(EmailValidator.java:95)....

-- Still double-check what Melody is doing.

If the problem was related to Melody, please let us know, just for personal information. I've seen so many random issues from people using that plugin, it looks useful but buggy.

Comment: I'm using the melody version 1.13, aka the last one. I'm currently isolating melody logs from the rest of the app.

Comment: My answer(wild guess) was related to the fact that the issues that you are seeing might be melody bugs. If you uninstall the plugin and you cannot reproduce the problem then it's definitely a melody bug, try it, what do you have to loose.

Comment: I wish it was melody, but no. Since i have List<User> in DataStore domain class, i have this error on the User's email validator, damnit

Answer (score 0):

You have the variable `dataStore` defined twice: once in your `hasMany` and once as a straight reference.

Try:

```
User entity: 
...

static belongsTo = [datastore: DataStore]

static hasMany = [groups: Groups,dataStores:DataStore]

Profile profile
Contacts contact

...
```